# How to call storyboard.TargetName from Xaml to C#

Tags: c#, xaml, storyboard

I want to rotate my 3D through xaml having this code

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation 
                                 From="0" To="360" Duration="00:00:10"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="angle"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                 RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>

    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

but when I try to run the code my project stops running giving me this error:
[image]

How can I add "angle" to my class XplorerMainWindow()?
and where should I put it. 
In the constructor, Somewhere in the class, in the function where I Open the file, or I have to create a new function?

Comment: What is `angle`? Please show its declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This is the "angle"

```
<Model3DGroup.Transform>
  <RotateTransform3D CenterX= "0" CenterY = "0" CenterZ="0">
     <RotateTranform3D.Rotation>
        <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="angle" Axis="-1, -1, -1" Angle="70"/>
     </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
   </RotationTransform3D>
</Model3DGroup.Transform>
```

and for your help I got this code from here this ebook that I have downloaded.
It is on page 87 of the pdf and page 1099 of the book
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3NndckqBKkBbTJVZW9tRXZmeTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ow and btw what my project is about, is that it Opens an XbimXplorer Window and it displays the model automatically on startup screen without using any menu items or buttons, but the model is declared and open through the c# code and not in xaml.